# Strange LLVM warning: no previous prototype for function for

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, llvm

If I missed the prototype, XCode (LLVM) prompt me for error

**no previous prototype for function for exceptionHandler**

But why they are needed in my code below?

```
void exceptionHandler(NSException * exception); // Why this Line is needed?

void exceptionHandler(NSException * exception)
{
    // ....
}

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&exceptionHandler);
...
```

Comment: are you concerns about declaration of method?

Comment: Is `exceptionHandler` defined in the same file as your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method? And, is it defined before its use?

Comment: @一二三 yes, all the codes are defined in AppDelegate.m

Comment: @DavidSchwartz No error, just LLVM warning show if I missed the function prototype

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're declaring a function only for use within this file, prefix the declaration with the `static` keyword and the warning will go away. As it is, you're declaring a global function; theoretically it could be called from anywhere within your app. But as you've given it no prototype, nobody else *could* call it.

So the warning, as I understand it, is trying to make you clarify your intentions between static functions and global functions, and discourage you from declaring a global function when you meant to declare only a static one.

Comment: Yes, I am using as global function. But as you can see, the warning goes away if I define the prototype ** in the** same file, so I suppose the visibility is still the same?

Comment: Yes, the visibility is the same, but the compiler now sees a prototype and assumes anyone can include the file with the prototype if they want to make the call. Only allowing a prototype in an .h file to quench the warning might have been better, but this is faster to detect (from a compiler point of view) and just as usefull (in my opinion).

Answer (score 18):

From the GCC manual:

> **-Wmissing-prototypes (C and Objective-C only)**
>
> Warn if a global function is defined without a previous prototype declaration. This warning is issued even if the definition itself provides a prototype. The aim is to detect global functions that fail to be declared in header files.

Clang borrowed this option for GCC compatibility, and because it's useful (I would presume this of the Clang devs).

The option exists so you can prevent yourself from making a common mistake which may be easily avoided. It's nice to be explicit about visibility/linkage for clarity/intent's sake.

In short, you've asked the compiler to tell you when an unqualified definition does not match a declaration by enabling this option. You should either qualify that as `extern` and make it usable to others (e.g. put it in a header), or declare it `static`. If using C++ `inline` is also an option.

Of course, implicit visibility is well known, but I typically find the option useful in these scenarios:

#### 1) I made a typo:

```
// file.h
extern void MONExceptionHandler(NSException * exception);
```

and

```
// file.m
void MONExceptionhandler(NSException * exception) {
  …
```

#### 2) I should be explicit about the symbol's visibility:

```
// file.m
static void MONExceptionHandler(NSException * exception) {
  …
```

#### 3) I forgot to `#include` the header which declared the function:

```
// file.h
extern void MONExceptionHandler(NSException * exception);
```

Warning:

```
// file.m
void MONExceptionHandler(NSException * exception) {
  …
```

No Warning:

```
// file.m
#include "file.h"

void MONExceptionHandler(NSException * exception) {
  …
```

So there's the rationale, history, and some examples - again, `-Wmissing-prototypes` is an *option*. If you trust yourself to work with it disabled, then do so. My preference is to be explicit, and to let programs detect potential and actual issues so I don't have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is most useful for C++ code. For example I have header

```
class MyClass {
public:
    void hello();
};
```

and .cpp file

```
void hello() {
    cout << "hello";
}
```

And you will see the warning because there are no prototype for function `void hello()`. In case the correct implementation should be

```
void MyClass::hello() {
    cout << "hello";
}
```

So this warning make sure you are implementing the function that you are aware of (not miss typed a name or different argument format).

Answer (score 0):

That warning is alerting that you can't call your method from another method that is written above. In C, the order of the declaration/implementation minds a lot and gives the difference between something that you can access or you can't.

Comment: The method he is calling is placed above. Your answer is technically correct, but useless for this question. Also, there are 2 other correct answers that were posted before you.

Comment: I don't think that I deserve a -1 for give an slightly different explanation, but the community decies ;)